# using case for include php

Tags: php, include, case

I made this quick example for my real website:
This is index.php:

```
<a href='?=page=homepage'>Home page</a><br>
<a href='?=page=news'>News</a><br><br>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
   $page = $_GET['page'];
   }else{
   $page = "";
   }


   include 'case.php';
?>
```

And this is my case.php:

```
<?php

switch($page)
{
   case "homepage":
   include 'homepage.php';
   break;
   case "news":
   include 'news.php';
   break;
   default:
   echo "this is default page";
   break;

}

?>
```

but it wont work, i made a homepage.php and news.php with some text in it. But the page will go to: `http://localhost:8080/?=page=news` and `http://localhost:8080/?=page=homepage` which doesn't work and show me the default case, but if i delete the `=` at the beginning to make `http://localhost:8080/?page=homepage` and `http://localhost:8080/?page=news` it will show me the correct pages...

Is there some really easy mistake i just made? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Change `<a href='?=page=homepage'>Home page</a>` to `<a href='?page=homepage'>Home page</a>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Holy .... i cant believe i missed that! Thanks so much for pointing this out, started to turn into a real pain in the a**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<a href='?page=homepage'>Home page</a><br>
<a href='?page=news'>News</a><br><br>
```

instead of:

```
<a href='?=page=homepage'>Home page</a><br>
<a href='?=page=news'>News</a><br><br>
```

Don't put an `=` sign between `?` and `page`

Comment: Yeah, i feel so stupid for missing this really obvious mistake.. can't believe i missed this =/ maybe because im tired.

Comment: Yeah, I make mistakes too when I don't get enough sleep. Working with a fresh mind, helps a lot. Glad this was resolved. @Farewyth Cheers

Comment: The question can be closed too ;-) @Farewyth Otherwise it will remain as "unanswered".